# How to stop the application

Tags: android

I have an application.It has an on / off button.
When you click on "on" it will calculate some big algorithm and it will give the result in 10 seconds.
When the algorithm is running (I don't want to wait 10 seconds) I want to stop it by clicking "off" but my app doesn't respond.
It even doesn't handle the onclick event for "off" button.
What can I do ???
Thanks

Comment: You're probably using the UI-Thread for your calculations. Make sure to use AsyncTask or a new thread for your calculations.
This makes sure your App stays responsible.

Comment: First off, if you don't want to wait 10 seconds then why do you have it running that long. Second, it would help if  you also posted some of your code here so we can see what your using and how you are implementing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use multithreading.  The main user interface thread must always be ready to respond to requests from the user, so doing any task that might take even 1 second is not recommended.  One way of doing multithreading in Android is to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) so I suggest you try using that.  With the big algorithm running in the background, the user interface could respond to e.g. an abort button.  You then need to program the background task to keep looking to see whether an abort has been requested.

Answer (score 2):

without code i can only guess, but it sound like you dong havy job on the main thread, consider using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)